# Apply SSL only to main domain - .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, ssl

We have purchased the FREE SSL from Hostgator. Basically you get it when you upgrade your package.

Now, we have one main domain (www.example.com) and 2 sub-domains (www.sub.example.com) & (www.sub.example.com).

I've inputted this code to .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Main domain works fine, but when I want to go to the sub-domain, I get redirected to the main domain => www.example.com .

I understand it's because of `^(.*)$` part, but what is the best solution to this?

I want the SSL only to main domain and the http to the subdomains.

Comment: Add a `RewriteCond` that checks if the host name is `(www.)example.com` first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a condition to exclude the subdomain from https redirection

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?sub\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. I have edited my question: I want the SSL only to main domain and the http to the subdomains.

Comment: My subdomain redirects me to the main page. => https://example.com , I want the subdomain to be http and the main site to be https.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. Now I have a question: is this SEO-friendly?

Comment: @Super11 Ofcourse this is. Read :
https://www.branded3.com/blog/seo-considerations-moving-http-https/